# Can't make my hamburger menu (absolutely positioned) vertically scrollable with FullPages.js

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, fullpage.js

Click the hamburger icon (top left) [on my website](http://goo.gl/iI3D9M) and se that the hamburger menu appearing on the left can be scrolled down.

Now check [the section using plugin Fullpages](http://goo.gl/gD1mjZ): click the same icon and try to scroll down the hamburger menu, it doesn't work.

By initializing the plugin using `scrollBar: true` I can make everything scrollable, but I want only the menu to be scrollable. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your menu element `<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">` inside a wrapper.

Set the size of the wrapper as the page height. Add the CSS style `overflow-y:scroll;` to the wrapper and then add the class of the menu wrap to the option `normalScrollElements` of fullPage.js.

Something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menuWrap">
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu"></aside>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menuWrap{
    height: 100%;    
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    loopHorizontal: false,
    scrollBar: true,
    normalScrollElements: '.menuWrap'
});
```